# "Generator" of a composite number

Tags: group-theory

Saying that I am aware what is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) I was wondering if the following has a name in standard mathematics:

Let assume I have a number n = 3 * 5

and e = 7

Then g ^ e (mod n) with 1 < g <  n produces all the number from 1 to n-1 e.g.

- 1 ^ 7 = 1 (mod 15)
- 2 ^ 7 = 8 (mod 15)
- 3 ^ 7 = 12 (mod 15)
- 4 ^ 7 =  4 (mod 15)
- 5 ^ 7 = 5 (mod 15)
- 6 ^ 7 = 6 (mod 15)
- 7 ^7  = 13 (mod 15)
- 8 ^7 = 2 (mod 15)
- 9 ^ 7 =9 (mod 15)
- 10 ^ 7 = 10 (mod 15)
- 11 ^7 = 11 (mod 15)
- 12 ^ 7 = 3 (mod 15)
- 13 ^ 7 = 7 (mod 15)
- 14 ^ 7 = 14 (mod 15)

This would not work with e.g. e = 8

Comment: What you have here seems completely unrelated to the existence of primitive roots. Any number coprime to $\varphi(n)$ will work. A primitive root is about taking different powers of a fixed element, rather than a fixed power of different elements.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I know isn't related to primitive roots. But does this have a name ?

Comment: Actually, I realized it might not work for all the numbers I claimed, since you take all the numbers rather than the units. Anyway, no idea about what one would call such a number.

Comment: If your base has a factor $p^2$ for $p$ any prime this will not work for powers other than $1$, because there will be residues with one factor $p$, but no powers with a single factor $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is square free and $\gcd(e,\lambda(n))=1,$ where $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael function, you are in the (multiprime) RSA setting (see e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447 ) and it can be show that $g\rightarrow g^e \bmod n$ is bijective. In this case you would call $e$  a **valid public key exponent**.